# Redshift showing 0 rows for external table, though data is viewable in Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I created an external table in Redshift and then added some data to the specified S3 folder. I can view all the data perfectly in Athena, but I can't seem to query it from Redshift. What's weird is that select count(*) works, so that means it can find the data, but it can't actually show anything. I'm guessing it's some mis-configuration somewhere, but I'm not sure what.

Some stuff that may be relevant (I anonymized some stuff):

```
create external schema spectrum_staging
from data catalog
database 'spectrum_db'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::############:role/RedshiftSpectrumRole'
create external database if not exists;

create external table spectrum_staging.errors(
  id varchar(100),
  error varchar(100))
stored as parquet
location 's3://mybucket/errors/';
```

My sample data is stored in s3://mybucket/errors/2018-08-27-errors.parquet

This query works:

```
db=# select count(*) from spectrum_staging.errors;
 count
-------
    11
(1 row)
```

This query does not:

```
db=# select * from spectrum_staging.errors;
 id | error 
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your parquet file and make sure the column data types in the Spectrum table match up.

Then run `SELECT pg_last_query_id();` after your query to get the query number and look in the system tables [`STL_S3CLIENT`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_S3CLIENT.html) and [`STL_S3CLIENT_ERROR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_S3CLIENT_ERROR.html) to find further details about the query execution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The types match up (as far as I can tell). I created the table with varchar(100) and wrote them with 'UTF8'. A parquet inspector shows me the parquet file has types: id: BYTE_ARRAY UTF8, error: BYTE_ARRAY UTF8. I tried the other steps, but I didn't get much information. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?
```db=# select * from spectrum_staging.errors; (0 rows)
db=# SELECT pg_last_query_id(); (330810)
db=# select * from stl_s3client where query=330810; (0 rows)
db=# select * from stl_s3client_errors where query=330810; (0 rows)```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define external tables when you have defined external schema based on Glue Data Catalog. Redshift Spectrum pics up all the tables that are in the Catalog.

What's probably going on there is that you somehow have two things with the same name and in one case it picks it up from the data catalog and in the other case it tries to use the external table.

Check these tables from Redshift side to get a better view of what's there:

`select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_SCHEMAS
select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES
select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS 
select * from SVV_EXTERNAL_COLUMNS`

And these tables for queries that use the tables from external schema:

`select * from SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY 
select * from SVL_S3LOG order by eventtime desc
select * from SVL_S3QUERY where query = xyz
select * from SVL_S3PARTITION where query = xyz`

Comment: I haven't tried using AWS Glue before. In any case, I saw the external table I created in the Data Catalog. I don't think there's an issue of duplicates, because if I delete it from the Data Catalog, it disappears from the list of external tables. Running your queries, the schema, table and columns are in SVV_EXTERNAL_* (The data isn't partitioned, so nothing in PARTITIONS). There were no errors in S3LOG. What's curious is that it does find the parquet files in S3_QUERY. But s3_scanned_rows and returned_rows are 0. s3_scanned_bytes shows that it read each parquet file. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe look again into the file creation. It may be that the fields are capitalized in the Parquet files or some other random crap like that (ID vs id). AWS Glue data catalog / table definition don't handle capital letters well for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

was there ever a resolution for this? a year down, i have the same problem today. 
nothing stands out in terms of schema differences- an error exists though

```
select recordtime, file, process, errcode, linenum as line,
trim(error) as err
from stl_error order by recordtime desc;
```

/home/ec2-user/padb/src/sys/cg_util.cpp padbmaster  1   601 Compilation of segment failed: /rds/bin/padb.1.0.10480/data/exec/227/48844003/de67afa670209cb9cffcd4f6a61e1c32a5b3dccc/0

Not sure what this means.

Comment: I got into contact with AWS and there was apparently a bug in Redshift spectrum that fails parsing parquets that are created with Decimal + Binary combination. 

The fix was to use fixed length binary array instead of binary.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when creating an external table in Athena using RegexSerDe row format. I was able to query this external table from Athena without any issues. However, when querying the external table from Redhift the results were null.

Resolved by converting to parquet format as Spectrum cannot handle regular expression serialization.

See link below:

[Redshift spectrum shows NULL values for all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212706/redshift-spectrum-shows-null-values-for-all-rows)